# SSL no suitable certificate found

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate

I know this is common error and that there are many duplicates of this question. Although they are I haven't been able to really find a true cause and fix my issue, so lets begin.

I'm using Kafka and on the server side in my truststore I have 4 chains. Each chain represents one Certificate Authority. Each chain was also imported as bundle (Interm + Root cert). 
Each broker has its own keystore of course and was signed by CA-1.

My client has certificates signed by CA-3. In truststore of my client I can list the same chains which are on my brokers.

Example:

1. Client tries to authenticate and has a certificate signed by CA-1 (**works**)
2. Client tries to authenticate and has a certificate signed by CA-2 (**works**)
3. Client tries to authenticate and has a certificate signed by CA-3 (**doesn't work**)

In debug mode on client I can find this:

```
check handshake state: unknown[13]
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=CA-1>
<CN=CA-2>
<CN=CA-3>
.
.
.
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
*** 
.
.
.
kafka-producer-network-thread | console-producer, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 3018
check handshake state: server_hello[2]
kafka-producer-network-thread | console-producer, fatal error: 10: Handshake message sequence violation, 2
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 2
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
kafka-producer-network-thread | console-producer, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 80
```

Now, what I don't understand. Application **was able to find trusted certificate of broker** (logs in the beginning I didn't want to put), was able to figure out in CertificateRequest all CAs available but it still fails to make a handshake.

Just to be sure - the way how I got Interm + Root certificate of failing client was that I downloaded Intermediate certificate and extracted Root one from Interm. Made a bundle with interm being first and root being second and that bundle i put under one alias in truststore and keystore.

I know this is most likely server trust error, but I don't know how to correct this since certificates are really there and the import of those certificate bundle I made in a same way I did for others which are working.

If I did something wrong, please correct me or even better, if I'm doing something wrong. I'm SSL nod and would like to learn things..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in my case and I think in lot of cases on stack was:

- I didn't have privKeyEntry in my client keystore

So if I would do:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore client.keystore.jks
```

I would find this:

```
primaryca, Jul 26, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <snip>
client, Jul 26, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):  <snip>
```

So as you can see there is no **PrivateKeyEntry** in keystore for client certificate.

So I started from scratch.

```
# Creating client keystore
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in client_certificate.crt -inkey client_certificate.key -certfile client_certificate.crt -out client.p12
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore client.keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS

# add bundle (interm + root)
$ keytool -keystore client.keystore.jks -alias CArootbundle -import -file bundle.pem
```

And now, after listing keystore:

```
CArootbundle, Jul 26, 2014, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <snip>
1, Jul 26, 2014, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):  <snip>
```

After I started my application with newly created keystore, eveything started to work :)

Hope I helped someone!

Cheers

Comment: The error here was that you didn't use the same alias when importing the signed certificate that you used when generating the keypair and CSR. Duplicate of many.